# Java double input

Tags: java, formatting, decimal

I am trying to let the user freedom of entering a number at his own style like he can choose to enter 2 or 2.00 but as you know the double cannot accept this (2). i want the double to accept this with 2 decimal places only (basically i am representing money).
 this is what i am not sure how to take the input and convert that in to the 2decimals format. New to java.tks

Tried google but cant find where i can format at the input itself, means dont even let the user type any more decimal places other than 2decimal places, not post-process after entered in to multiple different variables., tks

```
public static void add()
{
 double accbal;
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

        System.out.println("Enter account balance");
        accbal =  sc.nextDouble();
 //this is the part where i need to know the entered value is formated to only 2 decimal places

}
```

Comment: You might want to look into [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for better precision while handling money.

Comment: Never use `double` for money; always use `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to accept input of the form "#.##" just specify a custom regex for [`Scanner.hasNext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29) :-)

```
final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d{2}?");
while (input.hasNext()) {
  System.out.println((input.hasNext(pattern) ? "good" : "bad")
    + ": " + input.nextDouble());
}
```

Using the following input:

```
2.00
3.14159
2
```

The result is: (also found [here](http://ideone.com/OzLGE))

```
good: 2.0
bad: 3.14159
bad: 2.0
```

This way allows you to verify they enter an amount with two decimal places.

---

Even though you said you **do not** want a mere post-processing solution, in case you already have an amount and wish to convert it to use 2 decimal places, **and** you're focused on precision (since this is money), maybe try using [`BigDecimal`](http://goo.gl/9C8Ey) -- in particular, see [`BigDecimal.setScale`](http://goo.gl/c41Uy):

```
while (input.hasNextBigDecimal()) {
  System.out.println(input.nextBigDecimal().setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
}
```

The [output](http://ideone.com/NSXVN) is thus:

```
2.00
3.14
2.00
```

Comment: @Makoto that's because it answers the original question of restricting input.

Comment: @Makoto did you even read the OP? *i want the double to accept this with 2 decimal places only (basically i am representing money)*

Comment: Yes; the representation of numerical values is different than how one could pass them into the program.

Comment: @Makoto that is irrelevant here; he asked for a way to accept input with 2 decimal places *only* -- unlike any of the other 'answers' posted. I also showed an alternative to all of your solutions which actually rounds the value itself rather than just rounding the apparent result (hint: use `DecimalFormat.parse`) -- which can actually make a difference. I'm fully aware of the imprecision of floating-point, but even then `3.14` is not sufficiently close to `3.141498472` or whatever its nearest representable neighbor is (presuming it's not directly representable to begin with)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    DecimalFormat  df = new DecimalFormat ("#.##");//format to 2 places
    accbal =  sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.print(df.format(aacbal));//prints double formatted to 2 places
```

however I see you say:

> Tried google but cant find where i can format at the input itself,
>   means dont even let the user type any more decimal places other than
>   2decimal places

If the above is your intention for whatever reason then simply read in the input using `nextLine()` and then check to make sure after the decimal point it only has a length of 2:

```
double accbal=0;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

while (true) {
    System.out.println("Enter account balance");
    String s = sc.nextLine();

    if (s.substring(s.indexOf('.') + 1).length() <= 2)//accept input and convert to double
    {
        accbal = Double.parseDouble(s);
        break; //terminates while loop
    } else {
        System.out.println("Incorrect input given! Decimal places cant exceed 2");
    }
}
System.out.println("Balance: "+accbal);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since showing decimal places is really a formality to the end user, you could read your value in as a `String` instead and convert it to a `Double` or `BigDecimal`, the latter being preferred if you're working with actual finances.

Related:  [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

```
public static void add() {
    BigDecimal accbal; // could declare a Decimal
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

    System.out.println("Enter account balance");
    accbal = new BigDecimal(sc.nextLine());
    System.out.println(df.format(accbal.doubleValue()));

}
```